# onbeforeunload is called before ready in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below JS snippet to perform some action on browser or tab close/nevigate to other application.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {   
        $(".btn").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });
        $(":submit").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });
        $(":button").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });

        $("a").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });
        $("form").submit(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });
        $(":input").click(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
        });
    });
    localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("isReadyCalled") == "true" ){
            //Do some action
        }
    };
    localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","true");
</script>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla. 
In IE it works on most of the places. But sometimes it calls onbeforeunload before ready and that is causing the code in onbefore to be executed even if the flag is not set.

Not sure why its happening. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how about creating a boolean which you set to true when the document is ready? only if that bool is true you will execute the onbeforeunload code.

Comment: Tried that. Created a new boolean in ready code and set it to true. Once in onbeforeunload, tried checking it along with current  flag. It did not work.

Comment: you have to declare it outside of the ready function!

Comment: Actually I used localstorage to store it. so it act as global variable only.
Just for the sake of it, I also tried by creating a variable before ready.. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work?

```
<script>
    var is_ready = false;

    $( document ).ready(function() {   
        is_ready = true

        ...
    });
    localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","false");
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(!is_ready)
            return

        if(localStorage.getItem("isReadyCalled") == "true" ){
            //Do some action
        }
    };
    localStorage.setItem("isReadyCalled","true");
</script>
```

Comment: No this does not work. after clicking on a link its directly calling onbeforeunload() and there somehow its finding isready = true.... Not sure without going through ready block, how the value is changing to true.